# Cannot make webpack minify bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, minify

I am trying to minify my webpack bundles because right now it take about 25 seconds to load the website the first time.
The app.bundle.js is 11,989KB and vendor.bundle.js is 1,842KB
My own code is only a few KB.
When I check the content of the app.bundle.js most of the space is taken by the external libraries (react-dom, moment, react-bootstrap ...)

So I tried to minify them, but for some reason everything I am trying is not working.

I am not expert in webpack, so help from more knowledgeable people would be very welcomed.

Note: The webpack file I am using is from another project I used has a sample. So it might not be perfectly configured.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "a description.",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
    "babili-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.1",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.2",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.13.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.3.13",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.9",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.2",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "firebase": "^3.6.0",
    "history": "^4.5.1",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "invariant": "^2.2.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.2.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.11.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.4.2",
    "react-async-script": "^0.7.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
    "react-dnd": "^2.0.2",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.5.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^0.6.0",
    "react-gravatar": "^2.2.2",
    "react-helmet": "^4.0.0",
    "react-input-range": "^1.0.2",
    "react-modal": "^1.5.2",
    "react-page-click": "^3.0.0",
    "react-recaptcha": "^2.2.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-form": "^6.2.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.3.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "single-module-instance-webpack-plugin": "0.0.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "superagent": "^3.5.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.17",
    "xmldom": "^0.1.27",
    "xpath": "0.0.23"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node devServer.js --progress --verbose",
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist",
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch --progress --display-error-details --display-reasons",
    "start1": "webpack-dev-server  --config ./webpack.config.comphotdeploy -d --progress --colors --host localhost --port 28080 --hot --inline --content-base src",
    "builddev": "webpack -d --progress --display-error-details --display-reasons",
    "build": "webpack -p --progress --verbose",
    "dist": "rimraf ./dist&&webpack -d --display-error-details --display-reasons",
    "start-react": "SET PORT=9999&&SET DEVTOOL=source-map&&react-scripts start",
    "build-react": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "./node_modules/react-scripts/config/eslint.js"
  }
}
```

And my webpack:

```
var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var ProvidePlugin = require("webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin");
var CommonsChunkPlugin = require("webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin");
var LimitChunkCountPlugin = require("webpack/lib/optimize/LimitChunkCountPlugin");
var DedupePlugin = require("webpack/lib/optimize/DedupePlugin");
var SingleModuleInstancePlugin = require('single-module-instance-webpack-plugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var CircularDependencyPlugin = require('circular-dependency-plugin');

var BUILD_DIR =  path.resolve(__dirname,'dist');

var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

const BabiliPlugin = require('babili-webpack-plugin');

// http://dev.topheman.com/make-your-react-production-minified-version-with-webpack/
// https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/two-quick-ways-to-reduce-react-apps-size-in-production-82226605771a
// https://hackernoon.com/tricks-to-minimize-react-js-build-file-size-a35e355b8c64
var CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

// Load environment variables from .env file. Suppress warnings using silent
// if this file is missing. dotenv will never modify any environment variables
// that have already been set.
// https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv
require('dotenv').config({silent: true});

var PrintChunksPlugin = function() {};
PrintChunksPlugin.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
    compiler.plugin('compilation', function(compilation, params) {
        compilation.plugin('after-optimize-chunk-assets', function(chunks) {
            console.log(chunks.map(function(c) {
                return {
                    id: c.id,
                    name: c.name
/*,
                    includes: c.modules.map(function(m) {
                        return m.request;
                    })
*/
                };
            }));
        });
    });
};

var config = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: {
        app: APP_DIR + '/index.js',
        vendor: [
            'react',
            'react-dom'
        ]
    },

    output: {
        path:BUILD_DIR,
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        chunkFilename: "[name]-chunk.js",
        publicPath: BUILD_DIR
    },

  watch: false,
  watchOptions: {
    poll: true,
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    number: 1000
  },
  module : {
      loaders : [
          {
              test : /\.jsx?/,
              include : APP_DIR,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader?' + JSON.stringify({
                cacheDirectory: true,
                plugins: [
                  'transform-runtime',
                  'react-html-attrs',
                  'transform-class-properties',
                  'transform-decorators-legacy'
                ],
                presets: [
                    [
                        "es2015",
                        {
                            "modules": false
                        }
                    ],
                    'react',
                    'stage-2']
              })]
          },

          // CSS
          // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
          // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
          // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
          // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
          {
              test: /\.css$/,
              include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/style'),
              loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
          },
          // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
          // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
          // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
          {
              test: /\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
              exclude: /\/favicon.ico$/,
              loader: 'file-loader',
              query: {
                name: '[path][name][hash].[ext]',
                publicPath: '/'
              }
          },
          {
              test: /\.(ico)(\?.*)?$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              loader: 'file-loader',
              query: {
                  name: './images/[name].[ext]'
              }
          }
      ]
  },

     // use EnableCircularDependencyPlugin=true|false to check the option
  plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          // A common mistake is not stringifying the "production" string.
          'process.env': { 'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production') },

          // DISABLE redux-devtools HERE
          __DEVTOOLS__: false 
      }),

      // minify everything
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          compressor: {
              warnings: false
          }
      }),

      // Merge chunks
      new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),

      /*
      new CompressionPlugin({
          asset: "[path].gz[query]",
          algorithm: "gzip",
          test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
          threshold: 10240,
          minRatio: 0.8
      }),
      */

      // new BabiliPlugin(),

      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
          { from: APP_DIR + '/index.html', to: BUILD_DIR + '/index.html' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon.ico', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon.ico' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon.png' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-16x16.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-16x16.png' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-32x32.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-32x32.png' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-48x48.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-48x48.png' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-57x57.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-57x57.png' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-60x60.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-60x60.png' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-72x72.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-72x72.png' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-76x76.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-76x76.png' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-96x96.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-96x96.png' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-114x114.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-114x114.png' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-120x120.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-120x120.png' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-144x144.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-144x144.png' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-152x152.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-152x152.png' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-160x160.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-160x160.png' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-180x180.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-180x180.png' },
          { from: APP_DIR + '/images/favicon-192x192.png', to: BUILD_DIR + '/images/favicon-192x192.png' }
          ]),

      //new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({analyzerMode: 'static'}),
      //new PrintChunksPlugin()
    ],

      /*
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

            new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'permateam-core',
                minChunks(module, count) {
                    var context = module.context;
                    return context && context.indexOf('src\\') >= 0;
                },
            }),

            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'react-build',
                minChunks(module, count) {
                    var context = module.context;
                    return context && (context.indexOf('node_modules\\react\\') >= 0 || context.indexOf('node_modules\\react-dom\\') >= 0);
                },
            }),

            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'manifest'
            }),

            // uglfy / minify js
            new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                mangle: true,
                compress: {
                    warnings: false, // Suppress uglification warnings
                    pure_getters: true,
                    unsafe: true,
                    unsafe_comps: true,
                    screw_ie8: true
                },
                output: {
                    comments: false,
                },
                exclude: [/\.min\.js$/gi] // skip pre-minified libs
            }),

            new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({analyzerMode: 'static'}),
            //new PrintChunksPlugin(),

        //*********************************** async chunks*************************

        //catch all - anything used in more than one place
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            async: 'used-twice',
            minChunks(module, count) {
                return count >= 2;
            },
        }),

        //specifically bundle these large things
       new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            async: 'react-dnd',
            minChunks(module, count) {
                var context = module.context;
                var targets = ['react-dnd', 'react-dnd-html5-backend', 'react-dnd-touch-backend', 'dnd-core']
                return context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0 && targets.find(t => new RegExp('\\\\' + t + '\\\\', 'i').test(context));
            },
        }),

        return plugins;
    })(),
    */

    node: {
        net: 'empty',
        dns: 'empty'
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Did you try opening the bundle.js files and check to make sure if they already are minified? `new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    })` should minify it

Comment: Yes I did.
This is a sample of what is inside app.bundle.js

`function translate(number, withoutSuffix, key) {\n    var result = number + ' ';\n    switch (key) {\n        case 'm':\n            return withoutSuffix ? 'minuta' : 'minutę';\n        case 'mm':\n            return result + (plural(number) ? 'minuty' : 'minut');\n        case 'h':\n            return withoutSuffix  ? 'godzina'  : 'godzinę';\n        case 'hh':\n            return result + (plural(number) ? 'godziny' : 'godzin');\n        case 'MM':\n            return result + (plural(number) ? 'miesiące' : 'miesię`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to solve the problem even if I do not understand why the problem happens.

I was doing

> npm run dist

now I am doing

> npm run build

now the app.bundle.js is 1,765KB and vendor.bundle.js is 151KB

I still have some optimization to do to shrink further more the app.bundle.js but it is a good start already.

I would still like to know why the minify does not work with the dist if anyone has an idea.